# Pass values from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, class, react-hooks, components

I have the following 2 files where I need to pass value of the state variable checkedPpl from one component to another. I am learning React and any pointers would be of great help.

This particular project,  I am selecting a few names of people through checkboxes in FriendsList and want to pass those values to the FriendTagged component. I understand that I need to store those values as state variables in FriendsList and pass those to FriendTagged as props. Kindly suggest how this can be achieved.

**FriendsList.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import SampleImg from '../assets/SampleImg.jpg';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
//import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,withRouter,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import PeopleDataService from '../service/PeopleDataService';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';
import FriendTagged from './FriendTagged';
import PassValues from '../PassValues';
//import Navbar from './Navbar';





const Button=styled.button`

background-color:#3949ab;
color:white;
padding:5px 15px;
border-radius:5 px;
outline:0;
text-transform:uppercase;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow:0px 2px 2px lightgray;
`
const ListComp = {
    width: "300px",
    margin: "30px auto",
    backgroundColor: "#44014C",
    minHeight: "200px",
    boxSizing: "border-box"
   }

   const linkStyle = {
    margin: "1rem",
    textDecoration: "none",
    color: '#800020',
    backgroundColor: "#CFB997"
  };

   
   


class FriendsList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)        
        this.state = {
            isLoading:false,
            people: [],
            redirect:false,
            checkedPpl: []
            
        }
        
       console.log("inside constructor "+this.props)
        this.addFriendClicked = this.addFriendClicked.bind(this)
        this.refreshPeople = this.refreshPeople.bind(this)
        this.deleteFriendClicked=this.deleteFriendClicked.bind(this)
        //this.clickMe=this.clickMe.bind(this); 
        
    }
    addFriendClicked() {
        PeopleDataService.addFriendClicked()
       // this.props.history.push(`/save`)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshPeople();
        this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
        
        //this.setState({ people: body, isLoading: true });
        
    }
    deleteFriendClicked(){
        PeopleDataService.deleteFriendClicked()
    }
    refreshPeople() {
        
        this.setState({people: ["Jack","Jill","Louis","Emily","Donald","Holly"] })
           // alert(response.data);
    }
    

   /* refreshPeople() {
        PeopleDataService.retrieveAllFriends()//HARDCODED
            .then(
                response => {
                    console.log(response.headers);
                    this.setState({ people: response.data })//["Subin","Fiona","Evana"]
                    //alert(response.data);
                }
            )
           // alert(response.data);
    }*/
    toggleCheckbox = label => {
        console.log("Inside toggle checkbox "+label+this.selectedCheckboxes)
        if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(label)) {
          this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(label);
        } else {
          this.selectedCheckboxes.add(label);
        }
        this.setState({checkedPpl:[label]})
        //console.log('checkedPpl '+ "***" +label+"(((("+this.checkedPpl)
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    
      handleFormSubmit = formSubmitEvent => {
        formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();
        
    
        for (const checkbox of this.selectedCheckboxes) {
          console.log(checkbox, 'is selected.');
        }
      
      
        //this.setState({ redirect: true })
      }
    
     /*onSubmit = () => {
        {this.handleFormSubmit()};
        console.log("Inside onSubmit")
            this.props.history.push('/FriendTagged');
        
     }*/

      
      createCheckbox = label => (
        <Checkbox
          label={label}
          handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
          key={label}
        />
      )
    
      createCheckboxes = () => (
        this.state.people.map(this.createCheckbox)
      )
   
    

    render() {
      const {checkedPpl} = this.state;
      console.log("Parent value "+checkedPpl);
        return (       
            
           
                                  
                    <div className="container">
                        
        <h3 style={{ padding: "10px 20px", textAlign: "center", color: "#44014C"}}>Amigos  </h3>
        <div className="imgContainer">
        <h6 style={{ padding: "10px 20px", textAlign: "center", color: "#FF00FF"}}>Choose friends to tag on the photo</h6>
        
        
       <p></p>


        
        </div>

        <div className="tableContainer">
        <img src={SampleImg} width="250" height="200"/>
         <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ checkedPpl:this.state }) }}> 
        <table className="table">
            
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                
                                <th>Name</th>
                                
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >
                        {
                            
                                
                                          
                                             <tr>                                     
                                            {
                                            this.createCheckboxes()
                                            
                                            }
                                            <Link to="/component/FriendTagged" className="btn btn-default" style={linkStyle} type="submit">Tag</Link>
                                            
                                            
                                           
                                            </tr> 
                                        
                                       /* <tr > This displayed Tag and Remove buttons w/o names of people                                          
                                        <td>{person.name}</td>
                                        <td><button className="button btn-success" onClick={() => this.addFriendClicked(person.id)}>Tag</button></td>
                                        <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.deleteFriendClicked(person.id)}>Remove</button></td>
                                    </tr>*/
                                        /*<tr key={person.id}>                                            
                                        <td>{person.name}</td>
                                        <td><button className="button btn-success" onClick={() => this.addFriendClicked(person.id)}>Tag</button></td>
                                        <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.deleteFriendClicked(person.id)}>Remove</button></td>
                                    </tr>*/
                                
                            }
                          
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table>
                    </form>   
                    </div>
        
                
                    
                </div>
                    
            
        )
    }

    
}

export default FriendsList
```

**FriendTagged.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FriendsList from './FriendsList';
import sampleImg from '../assets/SampleImg.jpg';

class FriendTagged extends Component {
    
   

    render() {
        
        return (
            <div className="container">
    <h3 style={{ padding: "10px 20px", textAlign: "center", color: "#44014C"}}>Tagged Together</h3>
        <img src={sampleImg} width="250" height="200"/>
        
        <h6 style={{ padding: "10px 20px", textAlign: "center", color: "#FF00FF"}}>Friends tagged on this photo are:</h6>
        {this.props.data}
        
        
        </div>
        
        )
    }
}

export default FriendTagged
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use route state to send values via a route transition.

[Link to: object](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object)

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/component/FriendTagged",
    state: {
      friends: this.state.checkedPpl, // <-- pass the state here
    }
  }}
  className="btn btn-default"
  style={linkStyle}
  type="submit"
>
  Tag
</Link>
```

In the receiving component, `FriendTagged`, access the route state via the `location` prop.

[Route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props)

```
const { state } = this.props.location;
const { friends } = state;
```

#### Sidenote

It appears you've a bug in `toggleCheckbox` where you aren't appending, or removing, checked people from the `this.state.checkedPpl` state array, but rather always setting it to an array with only the last toggled value regardless of checked status. You'll want to sort this out as well.

```
this.setState({ checkedPpl: [label] })
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to pass data as props to another component , the component in question has to be the parent component to the component that receives the data -the child component. This data transmission is often refered to as 'passing through props'. In order for you to pass data through props from one component to another , your parent component has to return your child component:

```
const App=()=>{
 const handleSomething=()=>{}
 const handleClick=()=>{}
 const doSomething=()=>{}

 return(
<div>
  <ChildComponent hadleSomething={handleSomething} handleClick={handleClick} doSomething={doSomething}/>
</div>
)
```

The props you pass to the ChildComponent component are the data you are passing down from the parent to the child.

Answer (score 0):

in your `FriendsList` component add this line :

```
    render() { 
      return (
         ....
        <div>
          <FriendTagged data={this.state.checkedPpl} />
        </div>
        ....
        )
    }
```

then in your `FriendTagged` component use  `{this.props.data}` to recover your data.

Comment: I tried this by adding FriendTagged to the FriendsList component and the values are being carried forward as seen on the console log.             I had coded such that the navigation happens on a button click. So now all the values are passed down to the FriendTagged component but on button click it gets replaced with empty props. I hope I am clear about the issue

Comment: I edited my post, I suppose that you add correctly the checked peaple to `this.state.checkedPpl`

Comment: then in your btn, just redirect your app to render `FriendTagged ` component